# Use a class member type from a local variable

Tags: c++, types, member

If I have a variable declared with a complex type, such as:

```
std::unordered_map<PathKey,unsigned int> childDict;
```

Is there a way to declare variables using the sub-types of the main class type?

I would like to do something such as:

```
childDict::iterator iter = childDict.begin();
```

But this is not valid c++.

I know there are other alternatives:

- auto, but I try to avoid it for many reasons, including unreadability of the code. You don't figure out easily what the variable type is (is it an iterator? a pair? A pointer?). This problem is not present with the above method.
- typedef the type first, but if the above method was working, I think it would be more concise and the code would be very clear

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `decltype(childDict)::iterator`?

Comment: In my opinion, a tool should adopt to your needs, not you should adapt to the tool. This means, if your IDE keeps you from using auto, then you should look for another IDE. And use auto.

Comment: Just curious, what IDE are you using that has problems with 'auto'?

Comment: Or `decltype(childDict.begin())`. But indeed, try fixing your IDE instead.

Comment: I'm using qtcreator. Using another tool for developing a Qt application would imply loosing too much for balancing the auto type deduction gain. Don't tell me to choose another framework, or another target platform.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13794

Comment: And, besides the missing autocomplete features, I personally hate reading code with auto. That's a matter of taste and religion.

Comment: `auto it = childDict.begin();`?  Looks pretty clear to me what it is from this.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 `decltype()` will work:

```
#include <vector>
struct A {
    vector<int> v;
    void f() {
        decltype(v)::iterator i = v.begin();
    }
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I would argue if it's more readable than `auto`, though it's nearly exactly the syntax you wish for. I don't think there is another way to deduce type from a variable.